# Podman container cannot start after reboot

Tags: podman

I updated and rebooted Centos-9 VM. I tried to restart the podman containers then an error happened:

I tried with this command:

```
sudo podman restart --all
```

The result I got:

```
916dkawo6a5s20a614a607d810faddb44fbc3aeabc0e5153c20686723235ff30
vzhj7dym349d80610388cef97325025b36b9d152321022e44fe7368a2fca14df
1824ho6mz39nafc4a31cffc9a2e3a0e46e9e5e36bb2be38e0baf5aa08d2c109f
wuueb786509l4af016ba5194cec9a8bf36c23be03b5d0e82b5b5b94b002152f5
Error: crun: error stat'ing file `/var/run/docker.sock`: No such file or directory: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found
```

The last container cannot start due to missing file /var/run/docker.sock. How can I fix this? Really appreciate your helps .

I tried to enable podman socket with:

`systemctl --user start podman.socket`

Then created a symbolic link for docker and podman:

`ln -s /var/run/docker.sock /run/podman/podman.sock`

But I still got the same error.

Comment: Just a guess: Are you maybe using a bind-mount `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` for the `podman run` command? If so  try `-v /run/podman.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` instead